# Is there a way to access memory map as vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

**TL;DR** I have a large list of terms in a file which I have memory mapped. Can I access these terms as if they were a vector in memory. E.g., `std::string term = terms[1];`

### The File

I have a large binary file (which I create) containing millions of terms arranged like so:

```
applebarnhouseskytrain...
```

The header is a UInt64 int specifying the number of terms, followed by the same number of UInt64 ints, each specifying a byte offset for each term (starting at zero). The header for the previous example would look something like this (although in binary):

```
5 0 5 9 14 17
```

So the binary file altogether would look like [this](https://hexed.it#base64:Data;BQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAAAAAACQAAAAAAAAAOAAAAAAAAABEAAAAAAAAAYXBwbGViYXJuaG91c2Vza3l0cmFpbg==). **I am open to modifying the way this data is stored, if that will help.**

### The Memory Map

I am using the [mio](https://github.com/mandreyel/mio) library to memory map this file. I can iterate over the entire file, or access any individual byte. E.g.,

```
mio::mmap_source in;
in.map("index", error);
for (auto& b : in) {
    std::cout<<b;
}
std::cout << in[3];
```

I read the offsets in the header into a vector in memory:

```
std::vector<int64_t> offsets;
```

### Accessing a Term

Currently, if I want to access, say, the second term, I would first get the offset of the term `offset[1]` and the offset of the subsequent term `offset[1+1]`. Then I would create a `std::string term;` by looping through `in[]` using the offsets I just obtained.

### Questions

- Is there some datatype I can define so that I can access each term as if it were in an vector/set/map without loading actual terms into memory? E.g., `std::string term = terms[1]; //assigns "barn" to term`
- Am I going about this all wrong? Is there a faster, more efficient way of getting a term from a file? I have been thinking about the above for so long, I feel I might be missing other obvious options.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this. You can definitely define a `word_view` class or something that does this though.

Comment: You can use `std::string_view` to describe each term - you'll still need to write your own top-level container to look up the offsets and construct that view, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some datatype I can define so that I can access each term as if it were in an vector/set/map without loading actual terms into memory?

No.

With a custom allocator you could make a standard container use mapped memory for storage, but you couldn't use the data that was in the memory before the container took ownership.

You have to create a custom class for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I've been working on making a custom allocator, which if I can get working, I'll benchmark against just letting my OS put things in the swap file. A follow-up question, though, what do you mean by "you couldn't use the data that was in the memory before the container took ownership"?

Comment: @B.Wooster The container initialises objects into the memory. Whatever is in the memory will be overwritten. So it is not useful for reading a mapped file.